# Problem with Nette after update to PHP 7.4.6

Tags: php, xampp, nette

after upgrading PHP from version **7.3** to version **7.4.6**. everything I have in Nette throws out this message:
`Trying to access array offset on value of type bool`
In PHP 7.3. everything worked for me (even more complex projects). Checker is at 100% O.K. On the advice of the Nette forum, I also updated **Nette** to version **3.0**, but it's still the same. Where should I look for a bug?

```
Notice

Trying to access array offset on value of type bool search► skip error►
Source file
File: ...\vendor\nette\di\src\DI\ContainerLoader.php:109

 99:                throw new Nette\IOException("Unable to include '$file'.");
100:            }
101:            flock($handle, LOCK_UN);
102:        }
103:    
104:    
105:        private function isExpired($file, &$updatedMeta = null)
106:        {
107:            if ($this->autoRebuild) {
108:                $meta = @unserialize((string) file_get_contents("$file.meta")); // @ - file may not exist
**109:                $orig = $meta[2];**
110:                return empty($meta[0])
111:                    || DependencyChecker::isExpired(...$meta)
112:                    || ($orig !== $meta[2] && $updatedMeta = serialize($meta));
113:            }
Call stack
...\vendor\nette\di\src\DI\ContainerLoader.php:68 source  Nette\DI\ContainerLoader->isExpired(arguments)

...\vendor\nette\di\src\DI\ContainerLoader.php:47 source  Nette\DI\ContainerLoader->loadFile(arguments)

...\nette\bootstrap\src\Bootstrap\Configurator.php:267 source  Nette\DI\ContainerLoader->load(arguments)

...\nette\bootstrap\src\Bootstrap\Configurator.php:242 source  Nette\Configurator->loadContainer()

C:\xampp\htdocs\hello-world\app\bootstrap.php:20 source  Nette\Configurator->createContainer()

C:\xampp\htdocs\hello-world\www\index.php:3 source  require(arguments)

Variables
Exception
Environment
HTTP request
HTTP response
Report generated at 2020/08/23 03:10:12
http://localhost/hello-world/
PHP 7.4.6
Apache/2.4.43 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.6
Tracy 2.5.2
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtbVa.png) is the image of error stack.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [`unserialize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function failed so it returned `false`. And when the line after it is tried to use an index, it broke.

Looking into the [`nette/di` repository](https://github.com/nette/di/blame/766e8185196a97ded4f9128db6d79a3a124b7eb6/src/DI/ContainerLoader.php#L104), this was [fixed](https://github.com/nette/di/commit/4aff517a1c6bb5c36fa09733d4cea089f529de6d) in `nette/di` 3.0.1. Make sure you updated that dependency as well.